# c# crash dump does not exist

Tags: c#, crash-dumps

I have a C# application which crashes sometimes for unknown reason. Therefore, I want to find the crash dump file but it does not exist. I also wrote a small application which provokes a `DivideByZero` exception (unhandled). The consequences of this: on the one system the program closes without any message, on the other system (VM) I get a simple crash report which wants to send data to Microsoft.

I configured `drwtsn.exe` and the registry settings. I also tried to use `WinDbg` without success.

Does anybody know how I can force the system to write dump files?

Best regards,
el

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to write an event handler for the AppDomain.UnhandledException event.  Logging the e.ExceptionObject.ToString() value is almost always good enough, the stack trace tells you how the code got into trouble.

P/Invoking MiniDumpWriteDump() from dbghelp.dll is possible too, you'd get a .dmp file that you could use to analyze the exception with WinDbug.  Dbghelp.dll is available on Vista and Win7, you can get it from the [Debugging Tools for Windows](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/devtools/debugging/default.mspx) download for earlier versions.  However, you can't get good managed stack traces from that minidump, not until VS2010 ships.

Comment: thanks for your awnser, but the UnhandledException event is not called. My Application terminates without any hint.

Answer (score 1):

ADPlus is the easiest way.  Extensive documentation starts here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350

Comment: I would prefere a possibility with which a customer dont has to configure his PC. Is there any other way??? thanks in advice